# Is it good practice to use SharedPreferences as disk cache?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I need to cache an object to access it every and each `Activity` and `Fragment` in my app.

I tried to make it `static`, But , unfortunately, sometimes Android OS makes this static as null which crashes my app with no reason.

so is it a good practice to use `SharedPreferences` with `Gson` to serialize and 
cache the object on the disk?

Comment: yes use `SharedPreferences ` or `file` and store file in internal storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generaly, you shouldn't use **too much** the `SharedPreferences` as it's **not as fast as a local database**, but actually, you can use it if your **set of data is not too big** and if you just want a simple cache.

A simple alternative would be to use [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/#installation).

Comment: it is single object which contains only 8 variables. but intensively used in every activity..so i was thinking to use SharedPreferences in the beginning of every activity

Comment: yes, in `onCreate` or `onResume` load your data from SP and save it in a classic member. Btw, don't use `commit`, use `.apply()` on SP.editor

Answer (score 1):

`sharedPreferences` are designed to store data which should be retained between sessions.

If you need that object between the app launches then it's ok to use sharedPreference.

For your problem sharedPreference is a quick solution, however I still encourage you to find reason of your static variable being null.

Comment: the reason that Android OS is automatically null-ing objects to free some memory. so the problem of null shows up randomely

Comment: AFAIK android OS does not do that with static variables. there must be some other reason. how you came to the conclusion that OS is making it null?

Comment: It happened to me, and I read it here actually:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16736271/2296787

Comment: found something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541688/static-variable-null-when-returning-to-the-app). still it seems like bad design to store an entire object in shared preference.