# The best Android alternative to static Java objects

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm implementing an Android quiz in Java where user is shown a random image and is asked to choose what he can see in it. The images are in `/res/drawable`, however I'm wondering how to bind the image name and a few possible types of answers to the given image, each indicating something different about the person taking the test.

My first idea was to create a Java class serving this purpose:

```java
public class Question {
    Question(String imgSrc, String ans1, String ans2, String ans3)
    {
        imageSource = imgSrc;
        answer1 = ans1;
        answer2 = ans2;
        answer3 = ans3;
    }

    private String imageSource;
    private String answer1;
    private String answer2;
    private String answer3;
}
```

and then another class `QuestionSet` where specific questions could be constructed and stored as public static objects accessible from `QuestionActivity`. However, I'm reading that for some reasons static Java objects should be avoided in Android programs (as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736187/java-static-variable-becomes-null)), especially when they are to last in memory for a long time as is the case with my quiz.

So my question is what the best alternative for my current approach could be.

Comment: Just don't make it static. Put it in a regular class which is instantiated when needed. Although if you intend on having lots of data, putting it in some sort of database would be best.

Comment: @Nicolas The more I think about, the more advantages of using a database I see. Instantiation of scoped objects whenever needed probably won't work because I have to store member values somewhere anyway. And I don't want to run the risk of static objects so it seems database is the way to go.

Comment: You can look into prepopulated databases then. Room should work, but there are other alternatives too.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for the suggestion, Room is new to me but at first glance it looks great.