# Workaround for a final static variable whose lifetime has expired due to Activity being destroyed

Tags: android, static, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

[Reference to a question for Static lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023453/do-i-need-to-restore-all-variables-onresume/8023552#8023552)


I have been using final static variable to access SharedPreferences in Android, where i defined my final static variable **keys** for preferences in MainActivity.

**PROBLEM**

> When i get a push notification, and my MainActivity is dead or my application was not opened for a long time, These static variables give null values

**Question**

> How can i get a workaround for this to store my **Keys** for SharedPreferences, so that i can access them always.
>   1. Should i try to store them in sqlite database, and access them from there (a great headache),
>   2. Or is it good if i create all my static variables in the **GCMService**, which runs in background even when i receive my notifications. The problem is i am not sure how much memory will this method will consume

Answer (score 0):

Try Java coding as follows

```
    htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
// lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```